# Different View in Fragment for User

Tags: java, android

I'm working with fragments and I want to check if my User is registred (on Firebase) or if he's offline (similar to Spotify as you may know)

Anyway, I'm working on the following Code:

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private String userID;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Initialize Authentication Object
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unregistred, container, true);
        return view;
    } else {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, true);
        return view;
    }
```

As you may guess, this gives me an Error: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Research on removeView() didn't get me to the point, so I guess this is the wrong way to do it, am I right?

Full Crash Log as requested:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4937)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4768)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4708)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4681)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: I can't speak to your specific problem but i would suggest using two seperate fragments (or even activities) and checking login status in your activity to properly seperate logic for different use cases

Comment: post your full crash logs

Comment: I updated the Code

Answer (score 0):

When fetching details of the current user you need to call the `getCurrentUser()` method, which is missing in your code. Please try with the snippet down below:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```

For additional information and in case you need to look at more options on how to manage user's related information you can check the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)

If you need to check the current Network state of the user's device you can have a look at the answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android)

I hope that it helps :)

Comment: in my Code this is: mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();  with  if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) { .. so it should be the same as you posted

Comment: It's actually a different statement. Please pay close attention between the code differences and have a look at the provided link to the documentation :)